# Como utilizar a instrução Assert?

Tags: flutter, dart

A [Docuentação](https://dart.dev/guides/language/language-tour#assert) informa que:

> Durante o desenvolvimento, use uma declaração `assert` para
>   interromper a execução normal se uma condição for falsa.

A instrução `assert` garante por exemplo, a manipulação de valores `nulos` durante o desenvolvimento, evitando possíveis erros em tempo de execução.

Exemplo:

```
void main() {
  Nome(null).imprimir();
}

class Nome {
  Nome(this.nome) : assert(nome != null && nome.isNotEmpty);
  final String nome;

  imprimir(){
    print('Meu nome é $nome');    
  }
}
```

> Imprime: Meu nome é null //mas deveria gerar uma exception

Qual o motivo desse exemplo não se comportar da maneira esperada?

https://dartpad.dartlang.org/d98ad76b6e985e6cff27ecc7aea07d29

Comment: A opção `--enable-asserts` deve ser passada juntamente com o arquivo que será executado, para ativar os `AssertionError`s. Já [tentaram pedir que oferecessem um meio de ativar essa opção pelo DartPad](https://github.com/dart-lang/dart-pad/issues/310).

Comment: Isto é, dependendo da ferramenta também que está sendo usada para executar o programa, conforme diz a documentação.

Comment: @GustavoSampaio Se possível coloque como resposta exemplificando o uso no console Dart, ficaria ainda melhor com print do resultado.

Comment: Ok, vou elaborar a resposta.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Antes de tudo, vamos só contextualizar um pouco.

#### Mecanismos de depuração durante desenvolvimento

Muitas vezes se faz necessário, durante o desenvolvimento de uma aplicação, adicionar certos mecanismos de depuração para poder se ter noção se cada parte dela está funcionando da maneira adequada.

Esses mecanismos, ou ferramentas, podem vir de forma separada, ou até mesmo como uma característica já presente (acho que posso dizer, *nativa*) na linguagem que está sendo usada para desenvolver a aplicação.

Exemplos que se encaixam no grupo das "ferramentas à parte" são as ferramentas para elaboração de testes, além dos sistemas de depuração embutidos em IDEs (e alguns editores de textos).

E um exemplo que se encaixa no outro grupo é exatamente esse que aqui se trata, isto é, a estrutura `assert`, que serve para, em modo de desenvolvimento na maioria das vezes, atribuir condições que devem se tornar verdadeiras. E caso não se tornem, gerem uma interrupção.

#### Usando a estrutura `assert` em Dart

Conforme citei acima, e até como diz a [documentação do Dart](https://dart.dev/guides/language/language-tour#assert), a estrutura `assert` pode ser usada na sua aplicação para que haja uma interrupção na execução caso uma expressão retorne valor *booleano* **falso**, isto é, `false`. Usando até o exemplo dado na questão, pode-se entender isso:

```dart
void main() {
  Nome(null).imprimir();
}

class Nome {
  Nome(this.nome) : assert(nome != null && nome.isNotEmpty);
  final String nome;

  imprimir(){
    print('Meu nome é $nome');    
  }
}
```

Ou seja, a estrutura `assert` deve garantir (e mais uma vez lembro, **durante o desenvolvimento**) que o valor passado como argumento para o construtor da classe `Nome` (e que será guardado no campo `nome`):

- Não é nulo (`null`);
- E, sendo uma *string*, não é uma *string* vazia.

Além disso, você pode ainda fornecer uma mensagem customizada para caso a condição não seja atendida, dessa forma:

```dart
Nome(this.nome) : assert(nome != null && nome.isNotEmpty, "'nome' está se tornando nulo ou é uma string vazia");
```

#### Como executar da forma correta?

Dependendo de como o código-fonte será compilado, são feitos procedimentos diferentes, conforme diz a documentação.

**Usando a ferramenta [`dartdevc`](https://dart.dev/tools/dartdevc)**

Essa ferramenta, assim como o [`dart2js`](https://dart.dev/tools/dart2js), é utilizado para converter código Dart em código JavaScript, já que [o Dart também pode ser utilizado na *web*](https://dart.dev/web). A diferença é que o `dartdevc`, como o nome pode sugerir, é usado para desenvolvimento somente, portanto, ele deixa as estruturas `assert` ativas. Dessa forma, basicamente, para *compilar* usando essa ferramenta, usa-se isso:

```
dartdevc <nome_do_arquivo_fonte>.dart -o <nome_do_arquivo_resultante>.js
```

**Usando as ferramentas [`dart`](https://dart.dev/tools/dart-vm) e [`dart2js`](https://dart.dev/tools/dart2js)**

Já as ferramentas `dart` e `dart2js` (a última ainda mais por ser para produção) exigem que seja passada a opção `--enable-asserts` para que as estruturas `assert` funcionem. Assim, para *compilar* o código-fonte, faz-se:

```
dart --enable-asserts <nome_do_arquivo_fonte>.dart

// ou

dart2js --enable-asserts <nome_do_arquivo_fonte>.dart [-o <nome_do_arquivo_resultante>.js]
```

Caso não seja passada a opção, as estruturas `assert` que tiverem presentes não terão efeito.

E conforme pedido, aqui está uma *screenshot* do uso com e sem a opção:

[image: Screenshot dos comandos com e sem a opção '--enable-asserts']

E também com a mensagem customizada:

[image: Screenshot com saída customizada após falha no 'assert']

**Usando asserções no Flutter**

E para utilizar-se das asserções no Flutter, [basta que o *app* esteja sendo executado no modo *debug*](https://flutter.dev/docs/testing/debugging#debug-mode-assertions), que geralmente é o modo padrão durante o desenvolvimento.

---

Espero ter ajudado!