# Provider Flutter: Exception caught by widgets library

Tags: android, flutter, dart

Tudo bem ? estou com um erro após adicionar um initState com provider eu já não sei o que fazer, fiz de tudo e não resolveu meu problema, realmente eu estou perdido!

Depois que adicionei esse trecho no meu codigo ele me retorna erro

```
void initState(){
super.initState();
FishNotifier fishNotifier = Provider.of(context)<FishNotifier>(context, listen: false);
```

Essa é minha classe Notifier
[image: Essa é minha classe Notifier]

essa é minha main.dart

[image: main.dart]

Esse é o erro que persiste em me pertubar
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Acho que ali, em `Provider.of(context)<FishNotifier>`, a indicação do tipo deveria vir antes, não? Dessa forma: `Provider.of<FishNotifier>(context)`. Veja a [documentação: `Provider::of`](https://pub.dev/documentation/provider/latest/provider/Provider/of.html).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O problema que está ocorrendo pode estar relacionado à expressão que apontei nos comentários. Isto é, a seguinte expressão está escrita de forma inadequada:

```dart
FishNotifier fishNotifier = Provider.of(context)<FishNotifier>(context, listen: false);
```

O tipo que se fornece ao método estático `Provider::of<T>` (isto é, esse `T`) serve para identificar qual tipo de provedor de dados está a ser obtido. Porém, a forma correta de se passar esse tipo é:

```dart
FishNotifier fishNotifier = Provider.of<FishNotifier>(context, listen: false);
```

Da mesma forma que está a notação que coloquei acima, fazendo até com que se torne desnecessário o outro `(context)`.

#### Por que esse erro acontece?

O erro em si que foi gerado não está nem tanto relacionado a um possível erro de sintaxe, ou coisa do tipo, mas sim, a [uma asserção feita no pacote/biblioteca `provider`](https://github.com/rrousselGit/provider/blob/master/lib/src/provider.dart#L232-L241).

Essa asserção define que o tipo fornecido ao método `Provider::of<T>` não deve ser `dynamic`. Mas, talvez se diga:

> Mas, eu não passei `dynamic`! O que tentei passar foi `FishNotifier`!

Pois bem. Quando uma classe, método ou função, que usa [*generics*](https://dart.dev/guides/language/language-tour#generics) — ou seja, uma classe/método/função que pede um tipo que será internamente utilizado para definir variáveis ou métodos (esses, no caso das classes), evitando a duplicação de código — não recebe esse tipo que ela está pedindo ou aguardando, em Dart, considera-se que o tipo passado foi `dynamic`.

Ou seja, em `Provider.of(context)`, como "aparentemente" não foi fornecido o tipo que o método pede, então, forneceu-se o tipo `dynamic`, que é exatamente um tipo que o método disse que não deveria estar ali! Veja um exemplo dessa situação:

```dart
class Sequence<T> {
  final Iterable<T> _iter;
  
  Sequence(this._iter) : assert(T != dynamic);
  
  String toString() {
    return Set<T>.from(_iter).toString();
  }
}

void main() {
  // Roda normalmente
  Sequence<int> sequence1 = new Sequence<int>([1, 2, 3]);
  print(sequence1);

  // Se as asserções estiverem ativadas [1], gera uma exceção
  Sequence sequence2 = new Sequence([1, 2, 3]);
  print(sequence2);
}
```

Eu defino uma classe chamada `Sequence` que usa *generics*. Nesse caso, ela usa o tipo que está identificado pelo genérico `T` para criar uma variável que guarda um iterável (que pode ser uma `List` ou um `Set`, por exemplo) que retorne elementos desse tipo `T`. Porém, esse tipo `T` não deve ser `dynamic`, conforme defino no comando `assert`.

Na função `main`, estão dois exemplos. No primeiro exemplo, eu criei um objeto `Sequence` com o tipo `int`. Ou seja, o iterável a ser guardado deve retornar elementos do tipo `int`, que corresponde exatamente à lista passada como argumento (`[1, 2, 3]`).

Já no segundo exemplo, como eu não passei o tipo, ele fornecerá o tipo `dynamic`, o qual, na própria classe, eu havia definido que não deveria ser um possível valor para `T`. Assim, ele gerará uma interrupção<sup>[1]</sup>.

[1] - No Flutter, os comandos `assert` só funcionam no modo de depuração (*debug*). Quando se tratar do Dart somente, o funcionamento do comando `assert` dependerá de algumas coisas que você pode ver [nessa resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/449621/como-utilizar-a-instru%c3%a7%c3%a3o-assert/449832#449832).

Espero ter ajudado!

Answer (score -2):

Estava tendo um problema parecido com o Provider em relação a conexão com o Firebase. Quando chamava o provider na página de login dava um erro de (Exception caught by widgets library) e pedia para iniciar o Firebase.initializeApp(); porém já estava inicializado só que depois do MyApp();. Resolvi da seguinte forma:

---

### main.dart

```
Future<void> main() async {
   // Inicializando o Firebase APP e WEB
   WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();

   if (kIsWeb) {
     await Firebase.initializeApp( options:
     FirebaseOptions(
       apiKey: FirebaseApiWeb().ApiKey,
       appId: FirebaseApiWeb().AppId,
       messagingSenderId: FirebaseApiWeb().SenderId,
       projectId: FirebaseApiWeb().ProjectId,
     ));
   } else {
     await Firebase.initializeApp();
   }

   runApp(MultiProvider(
     providers: [
       ChangeNotifierProvider(
         create:(_) => UserManager(),
       )
     ],
     child: const MyApp())
   );
 }


class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    return MaterialApp(
        title: 'Loja Virtual BRN-Info_Dev',

        theme: temaPadrao,

        home: const BaseScreen(),
        debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      )
 }
}
```

---

### login_screen.dart

```
class LoginScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  const LoginScreen({super.key});

  @override
  State<LoginScreen> createState() => _LoginScreenState();
}

class _LoginScreenState extends State<LoginScreen> {

  final TextEditingController emailController = TextEditingController();
  final TextEditingController passwordController = TextEditingController();

  final GlobalKey<FormState> formKey = GlobalKey<FormState>();

    @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return Scaffold(
          appBar: AppBar(
            title: const Text('Entrar'),
            centerTitle: true,
          ),
          body: Center(
            child: Card(
              margin: kIsWeb
                  ? const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 150)
                  : const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 19),
              child: Form(
                key: formKey,
                child: Consumer<UserManager>(
                  builder: (_, userManager, __) {
                    return ListView(
                      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(16),
                      shrinkWrap: true,
                      children: [
                        TextFormField(
                          controller: emailController,
                          enabled: !userManager.loading,
                          decoration: const InputDecoration(hintText: 'E-mail'),
                          keyboardType: TextInputType.emailAddress,
                          autocorrect: false,
                          validator: (email) {
                            if (!emailValid(email!)) {
                              return 'E-Mail Inválido';
                            }
                            return null;
                          },
                        ),
                        const SizedBox(
                          height: 16,
                        ),
                        TextFormField(
                          controller: passwordController,
                          enabled: !userManager.loading,
                          decoration: const InputDecoration(hintText: 'Senha'),
                          autocorrect: false,
                          obscureText: true,
                          validator: (password) {
                            if (password!.isEmpty || password.length < 7) {
                              return 'Senha Inválida';
                            }
                            return null;
                          },
                        ),
                        Align(
                          alignment: Alignment.centerRight,
                          child: MaterialButton(
                            onPressed: () {},
                            padding: EdgeInsets.zero,
                            child: const Text('Esqueci minha Senha!'),
                          ),
                        ),
                        const SizedBox(
                          height: 16,
                        ),
                        SizedBox(
                          height: 52,
                          child: CustomButton(
                            texto: 'Entrar',
                              onPressed: userManager.loading ? null : () {
                                if (formKey.currentState!.validate()) {
                                  userManager.signIn(
                                      users: Users(
                                          email: emailController.text,
                                          password: passwordController.text),
                                      onFail: (error) {
                                        ScaffoldMessenger.of(context)
                                            .showSnackBar(SnackBar(
                                              content: Text(error,
                                              style: const TextStyle(fontSize: 18)),
                                          backgroundColor: Colors.red,
                                        ));
                                      },
                                      onSuccess: () {
                                        debugPrint("Sucesso  no login");
                                        // TODO: FECHAR TELA DE LOGIN
                                      }
                                      );
                                }
                              },
                          ),
                        ),
                      ],
                    );
                  },
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
        );
      }
    }
```

---

### user_manager.dart

```
class UserManager with ChangeNotifier{

  final FirebaseAuth auth = FirebaseAuth.instance;
  bool loading = false;

  Future<void> signIn({required Users users, required Function onFail, required Function onSuccess}) async {
    setLoading(true);
    try{
      final UserCredential result = await auth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(
          email: users.email, password: users.password);

      await Future.delayed(const Duration (seconds: 4)); //Teste temporal

      onSuccess();
    } on FirebaseAuthException catch(error){
      onFail(getErrorString(error.code));
    }
    setLoading(false);
  }
  void setLoading(bool value){
    loading = value;
    notifyListeners();
  }
}
```

Comment: Espero ajudar alguém foram um dia e meio nesta peleja!!!!kkkkk