# Teste de validação funciona com valores numéricos, mas não com strings

Tags: orientação-a-objetos, dart

Meu código de herança funciona normal, o que eu queria fazer é que **caso o `nome` e o `pseudonimo` sejam `null` o código pararia**, o código **só para de executar quando `idade`, `altura` ou `peso` são `null`**.

```dart
import 'dart:io';
 
main() {

  var humano = Humano();
  var pessoa = Pessoa();

  stdout.write("Digite o seu nome: ");
  pessoa.nome = stdin.readLineSync();
  if (pessoa.nome == null) return;
  stdout.write("Digite o seu pseudônimo: ");
  pessoa.pseudonimo = stdin.readLineSync();
  if (pessoa.pseudonimo == null) return;
  stdout.write("Digite a sua idade: ");
  pessoa.idade = int.tryParse(stdin.readLineSync());
  if (pessoa.idade == null) return;
  stdout.write("\n");

  stdout.write("Digite o seu peso: ");
  humano.peso = double.tryParse(stdin.readLineSync());
  if (humano.peso == null) return;
  stdout.write("Digite o sua altura: ");
   humano.altura = double.tryParse(stdin.readLineSync());
  if (humano.altura == null) return;
  stdout.write("\n");

  print("Nome: ${pessoa.nome}");
  print("Idade: ${pessoa.idade}"); 
  print("Pseudônimo: ${pessoa.pseudonimo}");
  print("Altura: ${humano.altura}cm");
  print("Peso: ${humano.peso}kg");

}

class Humano {

  double peso;
  double altura;

  Humano({this.peso, this.altura});

}

class Pessoa extends Humano {

  String nome;
  String pseudonimo;
  int idade;

  Pessoa({this.nome, this.pseudonimo, this.idade});
  
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Antes de tudo, vamos notar algumas coisas.

#### Não são necessários dois objetos, quando um pertence a uma subclasse do outro

De acordo com o que você colocou na pergunta, a classe `Pessoa` herda (estende) da classe `Humano` – além disso, não sei se é realmente necessária essa classe.

Se, de fato, ela herda, então, não é necessário você criar um objeto de `Pessoa` e um objeto de `Humano` para poder utilizar os membros de cada uma, já que *a primeira* **deveria ter os membros** *da segunda*!

O que parece que está acontecendo, é que você não está chamando o construtor da superclasse de `Pessoa` (a classe `Humano`). Ou seja, apesar de você herdar da classe, você não pede para ela tratar os dados que são cabíveis a ela.

Para isso, você utiliza o [comando `super`](https://dart.dev/guides/language/language-tour#extending-a-class), que (em diversas linguagens) serve exatamente para chamar o construtor da superclasse (*classe-mãe*) de uma classe.

```dart
class Humano {

  double peso;
  double altura;

  Humano({this.peso, this.altura});
}

class Pessoa extends Humano {

  String nome;
  String pseudonimo;
  int idade;

  Pessoa({double peso, double altura, this.nome, this.pseudonimo, this.idade})
    : super(peso: peso, altura: altura); 
}
```

Ou seja, eu pego os parâmetros `peso` e `altura` e passo para o construtor da classe que irá lidar com eles, ou seja, o construtor da [super]classe `Humano`!

#### Obtendo os dados primeiro e criando o objeto depois

Outra coisa que poderíamos modificar, é que ao invés de você criar o objeto "vazio" e preencher os seus campos à medida que vai pedindo ao usuário – o que parece um pouco com o que, às vezes, se faz com as `struct`s em C – na minha opinião, poderia ficar melhor se você obtivesse esses dados primeiro, e depois passasse-os para o construtor da classe `Pessoa`:

```dart
main() {
  double peso, altura;
  String nome, pseudonimo;
  int idade;

  stdout.write("Digite o seu nome: ");
  nome = stdin.readLineSync();
  
  stdout.write("Digite o seu pseudônimo: ");
  pseudonimo = stdin.readLineSync();
  
  stdout.write("Digite a sua idade: ");
  idade = int.tryParse(stdin.readLineSync());

  stdout.write("Digite o seu peso: ");
  peso = double.tryParse(stdin.readLineSync());
  
  stdout.write("Digite a sua altura: ");
  altura = double.tryParse(stdin.readLineSync());
  
  stdout.write("\n");

  var pessoa = new Pessoa(
    peso: peso,
    altura: altura,
    nome: nome,
    pseudonimo: pseudonimo,
    idade: idade
  );
  
  print("Nome: ${pessoa.nome}");
  print("Idade: ${pessoa.idade}");
  print("Pseudônimo: ${pessoa.pseudonimo}");
  print("Altura: ${pessoa.altura}cm");
  print("Peso: ${pessoa.peso}kg");
}
```

Pois, assim, você tanto estará fazendo o uso apropriado do construtor, como também poderá deixar o código um pouco mais "organizado", através ainda da próxima sugestão.

#### Validando os dados dentro da classe

Pedindo os dados primeiro e criando o objeto depois, dá margem para que você faça a validação dos dados **na própria classe**!

Na minha perspectiva, eu acho que isso também é o melhor a se fazer, pois *a classe será a responsável por estabelecer as "regras"*, da mesma forma que numa espécie de estrutura MVC, a camada *Model* é a responsável pelas *regras de negócio*. Entretanto, ao final, apresentarei uma pequena desvantagem da utilização desse método.

Mas, vamos à solução do problema!

#### Resolvendo o real problema

Quando você usa a [função `stdin.readLineSync`](https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.10.2/dart-io/Stdin/readLineSync.html), ela irá retornar **uma *string***! Portanto, se você não digitar nada, ao invés de retornar `null`, ela retornará uma *string* vazia (`""`).

Já o [método estático `int.tryParse`](https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.10.2/dart-core/int/tryParse.html), ao tentar converter o valor que lhe foi passado, seu retorno pode ser um inteiro (`int`), ou `null`, o último quando a conversão não foi bem-sucedida. Do mesmo modo, o [método estático `double.tryParse`](https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.10.2/dart-core/double/tryParse.html) (só que, ao invés de `int`, retorna um `double`).

E com isso, descobrimos o porquê de o teste de `null` para `idade`, `altura` e `peso` dar certo: pois, quando o usuário não digita nada, a *string* vazia é convertida por esses métodos para `null`!

Por isso, para validar os dados que são *strings*, nós devemos utilizar as propriedades que servem exatamente para saber se uma *string* é vazia, ou não. São elas: [`String#isEmpty`](https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.10.2/dart-core/String/isEmpty.html) e [`String#isNotEmpty`](https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.10.2/dart-core/String/isNotEmpty.html).

Assim, agora com o objetivo de fazer a validação na classe, nós podemos optar por utilizar técnicas manuais, dessa forma:

```dart
class Humano {

  double peso;
  double altura;

  Humano({this.peso, this.altura}) {
    if (peso == null || altura == null) {
      throw new Exception("os campos 'peso' e 'altura' não devem ser nulos!");
    }
  }
}

class Pessoa extends Humano {

  String nome;
  String pseudonimo;
  int idade;

  Pessoa({double peso, double altura, this.nome, this.pseudonimo, this.idade})
    : super(peso: peso, altura: altura)
  {
    if (nome.isEmpty || pseudonimo.isEmpty || idade == null) {
      throw new Exception("os campos 'nome', 'pseudonimo' e 'idade' não devem ser nulos ou vazios!");
    }
  } 
}
```

Ou então, podemos optar por utilizar comandos fornecidos pela própria linguagem, como o comando `assert`, sobre o qual você pode saber mais [nesse post](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/449621/125486)!

Com ele, o código poderia ficar ainda menor:

```dart
class Humano {

  double peso;
  double altura;

  Humano({this.peso, this.altura})
    : assert(peso != null && altura != null,
             "os campos 'peso' e 'altura' não devem ser nulos!");
}

class Pessoa extends Humano {

  String nome;
  String pseudonimo;
  int idade;

  Pessoa({double peso, double altura, this.nome, this.pseudonimo, this.idade})
    : assert(nome.isNotEmpty && pseudonimo.isNotEmpty && idade != null,
             "os campos 'nome', 'pseudonimo' e 'idade' não devem ser nulos ou vazios!"),
      super(peso: peso, altura: altura);
}
```

> **OBS.:** quando você utilizar outros comandos de inicialização junto com o `super`, com essa sintaxe, sempre coloque o `super` por último! Caso contrário, irá gerar um erro!

Em ambos os códigos, fazemos com que:

- A classe `Pessoa` garanta que os dados de `nome` e `pseudonimo` não sejam vazios, e o dado de `idade` não seja `null`;
- A classe `Humano` garanta que os dados de `peso` e `altura` não seja `null`.

Porém, no segundo caso, você tem que se atentar ao que é dito naquela resposta – sobre a ativação do comando `assert` – pois, caso esteja desativado, a validação não terá efeito!

---

No final de tudo, o seu código deve ficar assim:

**Forma com validação manual**

```dart
import "dart:io";

main() {
  double peso, altura;
  String nome, pseudonimo;
  int idade;

  stdout.write("Digite o seu nome: ");
  nome = stdin.readLineSync();
  
  stdout.write("Digite o seu pseudônimo: ");
  pseudonimo = stdin.readLineSync();
  
  stdout.write("Digite a sua idade: ");
  idade = int.tryParse(stdin.readLineSync());

  stdout.write("Digite o seu peso: ");
  peso = double.tryParse(stdin.readLineSync());
  
  stdout.write("Digite a sua altura: ");
  altura = double.tryParse(stdin.readLineSync());
  
  stdout.write("\n");

  var pessoa = new Pessoa(
    peso: peso,
    altura: altura,
    nome: nome,
    pseudonimo: pseudonimo,
    idade: idade
  );
  
  print("Nome: ${pessoa.nome}");
  print("Idade: ${pessoa.idade}");
  print("Pseudônimo: ${pessoa.pseudonimo}");
  print("Altura: ${pessoa.altura}cm");
  print("Peso: ${pessoa.peso}kg");
}

class Humano {

  double peso;
  double altura;

  Humano({this.peso, this.altura}) {
    if (peso == null || altura == null) {
      throw new Exception("os campos 'peso' e 'altura' não devem ser nulos!");
    }
  }
}

class Pessoa extends Humano {

  String nome;
  String pseudonimo;
  int idade;

  Pessoa({double peso, double altura, this.nome, this.pseudonimo, this.idade})
    : super(peso: peso, altura: altura)
  {
    if (nome.isEmpty || pseudonimo.isEmpty || idade == null) {
      throw new Exception("os campos 'nome', 'pseudonimo' e 'idade' não devem ser nulos ou vazios!");
    }
  } 
}
```

**Forma com validação com `assert`**

```dart
import "dart:io";

main() {
  double peso, altura;
  String nome, pseudonimo;
  int idade;

  stdout.write("Digite o seu nome: ");
  nome = stdin.readLineSync();
  
  stdout.write("Digite o seu pseudônimo: ");
  pseudonimo = stdin.readLineSync();
  
  stdout.write("Digite a sua idade: ");
  idade = int.tryParse(stdin.readLineSync());
  
  stdout.write("\n");

  stdout.write("Digite o seu peso: ");
  peso = double.tryParse(stdin.readLineSync());
  
  stdout.write("Digite o sua altura: ");
  altura = double.tryParse(stdin.readLineSync());
  
  stdout.write("\n");

  var pessoa = new Pessoa(
    peso: peso,
    altura: altura,
    nome: nome,
    pseudonimo: pseudonimo,
    idade: idade
  );
  
  print("Nome: ${pessoa.nome}");
  print("Idade: ${pessoa.idade}");
  print("Pseudônimo: ${pessoa.pseudonimo}");
  print("Altura: ${pessoa.altura}cm");
  print("Peso: ${pessoa.peso}kg");
}

class Humano {

  double peso;
  double altura;

  Humano({this.peso, this.altura})
    : assert(peso != null && altura != null,
             "os campos 'peso' e 'altura' não devem ser nulos!");
}

class Pessoa extends Humano {

  String nome;
  String pseudonimo;
  int idade;

  Pessoa({double peso, double altura, this.nome, this.pseudonimo, this.idade})
    : assert(nome.isNotEmpty && pseudonimo.isNotEmpty && idade != null,
             "os campos 'nome', 'pseudonimo' e 'idade' não devem ser nulos ou vazios!"),
      super(peso: peso, altura: altura);
}
```

#### Conclusão

Um ponto, porém, que faz o programa agir de forma diferente, é que a validação só será feita quando todos os dados tiverem sido preenchidos. Ou seja, o usuário não terá um retorno imediato sobre a validade daquele dado inconsistente que ele forneceu.

Apesar disso, agora, o funcionamento do programa estará da forma que (acho que) se espera e ainda com um código, na minha opinião, um pouco melhor separado e "organizado"!

Outra coisa também sobre a qual poderia ter falado na resposta, mas que optei por não fazê-lo, é sobre [o novo sistema de tipos com *null-safety* do Dart](https://dart.dev/null-safety). Ele mudaria **muito** o jeito que você escreveria esse código! Só que, como ele ainda não é obrigatório, então não quis fazer cobertura sobre ele agora. Mas, quem sabe, no futuro, eu possa adicionar algo sobre isso! :)

Comment: Interessante sua explicação, obrigado.